# CSS Animation: Why is one keyframe skipped?

Tags: css, animation

I've got this picture slideshow made with CSS keyframes.

Here is everything fine:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom left, white, #cdcdcd);
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, white, #cdcdcd);
}
.wrap {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
img {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 3px;
  border: solid 1px;
}
img:nth-of-type(1) {
  -webkit-animation: changeOpacity 10s infinite;
  animation: changeOpacity 10s infinite;
}
img:nth-of-type(2) {
  -webkit-animation: changeOpacity 10s 2s infinite;
  animation: changeOpacity 10s 2s infinite;
}
img:nth-of-type(3) {
  -webkit-animation: changeOpacity 10s 4s infinite;
  animation: changeOpacity 10s 4s infinite;
}
img:nth-of-type(4) {
  -webkit-animation: changeOpacity 10s 6s infinite;
  animation: changeOpacity 10s 6s infinite;
}
img:nth-of-type(5) {
  -webkit-animation: changeOpacity 10s 8s infinite;
  animation: changeOpacity 10s 8s infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes changeOpacity {
  0% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  20.1% {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
}
@keyframes changeOpacity {
  0% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  20.1% {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <img width="640" height="420" src="http://placehold.it/640/ff0000" alt="pict" />
  <img width="640" height="420" src="http://placehold.it/640/00ff00" alt="pict" />
  <img width="640" height="420" src="http://placehold.it/640/0000ff" alt="pict" />
  <img width="640" height="420" src="http://placehold.it/640/ff00ff" alt="pict" />
  <img width="640" height="420" src="http://placehold.it/640/00ffff" alt="pict" />
</div>
```

The cyan image (00ffff) disappears and the red image (ff0000) appears **at once.** There is no transition between the two.

But it is only therefore fine because I've got that additional keyframe. ...

```
...
20.1% {
    opacity: 1.0; 
}
...
```

... in there.

I've one removes that keyframe then the behavior starts to change:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom left, white, #cdcdcd);
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, white, #cdcdcd);
}
.wrap {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
img {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 3px;
  border: solid 1px;
}
img:nth-of-type(1) {
  -webkit-animation: changeOpacity 10s infinite;
  animation: changeOpacity 10s infinite;
}
img:nth-of-type(2) {
  -webkit-animation: changeOpacity 10s 2s infinite;
  animation: changeOpacity 10s 2s infinite;
}
img:nth-of-type(3) {
  -webkit-animation: changeOpacity 10s 4s infinite;
  animation: changeOpacity 10s 4s infinite;
}
img:nth-of-type(4) {
  -webkit-animation: changeOpacity 10s 6s infinite;
  animation: changeOpacity 10s 6s infinite;
}
img:nth-of-type(5) {
  -webkit-animation: changeOpacity 10s 8s infinite;
  animation: changeOpacity 10s 8s infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes changeOpacity {
  0% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
}
@keyframes changeOpacity {
  0% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <img width="640" height="420" src="http://placehold.it/640/ff0000" alt="pict" />
  <img width="640" height="420" src="http://placehold.it/640/00ff00" alt="pict" />
  <img width="640" height="420" src="http://placehold.it/640/0000ff" alt="pict" />
  <img width="640" height="420" src="http://placehold.it/640/ff00ff" alt="pict" />
  <img width="640" height="420" src="http://placehold.it/640/00ffff" alt="pict" />
</div>
```

One can see that the first image (the red one (ff00000) is almost skipped. 
The cyan image appears. Then there a transition of some grey-cyan. Then the green image (00ff00) appears.

**What's the reason for that behavior?**

What happens there?

Comment: The main problem here is you start animate the first element `nth-child(1)`, which is at the bottom of the layer, where you should start from the fifth `nth-child(5)` ... on top of that, for the loop/keyframe/timing, it is a little more complex to make it look good, check this post of mine on how to: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40317619/2827823

Comment: If you find my linked post in my previous comment answering your question, I'll vote to close this as a duplicate, if not, let me know how it doesn't and I'll consider post an answer here.

Comment: Your post is definitely helpful and I've got a better idea now about how keyframes work. Just go ahead closing this question. But anyway: Thanks a lot ! :)

Comment: What @LGSon has said is correct (about the placement order of the images). The reason for the grey-cyan (or some intermediate colors) is that when you transition or animation opacity from 1 to 0, it goes through stages like `opacity: 0.9`, `opacity: 0.8` etc and during such times it has the effect of placing a translucent cyan on top of a pink/red (basically the color below) and thus it results in some *combination* colors.

Comment: I'm closing the question based on your response to LGSon :)