# how to display background image one by one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

css code

```
#intro  {
        position: relative;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center top;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 15.6rem;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
#intro > figure {
              animation: imageAnimation 30s linear infinite 0s;
              backface-visibility: hidden;
              background-size: cover;
              background-position: center center;
              color: transparent;
              height: 100%;
              left: 0px;
              opacity: 0;
              position: absolute;
              top: 0px;
              width: 100%;
              z-index: 0;
              margin-left: 0px;
            }
#intro > figure:nth-child(1){
                            background-image: url('../images/1.jpg');
                        }
#intro > figure:nth-child(2){
                          animation-delay: 6s;
                          background-image: url('../images/2.jpg');
                        }
#intro > figure:nth-child(3){
                          animation-delay: 12s;
                          background-image: url('../images/3.jpg');
                        }
```

html code:

```
 <section id="intro">
    <figure></figure>
    <figure></figure>
    <figure></figure>
 </section>
```

In this code I am going to display background image one by one but here when background image fade out one by one after third image its display black background. So, How can I remove black color background I want to display only images using css.

Thank You

Comment: may any one help me plsss

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Full background image with fade effect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40316527/full-background-image-with-fade-effect)

Comment: Sir may you edit in my code

Comment: It is in your own interest to understand how this work, so I suggest you give it a go yourself and then come back if you can't make it work

Answer (score 0):

If there isn't reason avoid jQuery plugins, just try to use [Slick carousel](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/).

Take a look to "fade", it works great.