# how to counter attack a xmlrpc.php attack

Tags: wordpress, xml-rpc, brute-force

I want to counter attack or flood the attacker with useless data a loop or something... ?

Having a high rate of xml-rpc attacks and since i dont use xml-rpc and am currently routing them to a shame on you html page, but thought it would be innovative to either counter attack or simply respond to the data request with a flood of useless data preferably never ending flood till they escape it :)

Comment: Try [keyframes](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp)

Comment: Like this? ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40316527/full-background-image-with-fade-effect

Comment: tried that not working :)

Comment: You mean my linked sample does not work?

Answer (score 0):

Try css transition property with slide time.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this in jQuery. After clicking I would do a clearInterval();

Note: Add jQUery library before testing this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      setInterval(functionToExecute, 30000);
      });

    function functionToExecute(){
      setTimeout(slide1, 5000);
      setTimeout(slide2, 10000);
      setTimeout(slide3, 15000);
      setTimeout(slide4, 20000);
    }

    function slide1(){
      $("#slide-1-trigger").trigger("click");
    }
      function slide2(){
      $("#slide-2-trigger").trigger("click");
    }
      function slide3(){
      $("#slide-3-trigger").trigger("click");
    }
      function slide4(){
      $("#slide-4-trigger").trigger("click");
    }
```